# Java permutations of custom array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, permutation, repeat

Currently, I am working on a program to generate the optimal setup for my track and field competition. I have some objects of the class Person (which is custom-made of course) and they all have a name (-String).
Now, I want to generate a list of all possible setups. Consider it as a group of persons that have to do a number of tasks. Example (two persons, two tasks):

`Person1 doing both tasks, Person1 doing first task and Person2 doing second, Person2 doing first task and Person1 doing second, Person2 doing both tasks`

Now I want to this with an unknown number of 'tasks' and persons, so pre-programmed loops don't look like a solution to me. In my opinion recursion is the way to go, but I haven't quite figured it out. 
Consider the setup as an array of Persons, and I know what the first indice means, so just printing the names of the Persons will do. (Like: `Person1, Person2` or something.)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "pre-programmed loops"?

Comment: Like, I can't create loops to go down all possibilities as I don't know how many there will be.

Comment: You can use mathematical expressions and function calls in a for loop, e.g. `for(int i = 0; i < peopleArray.length; i++)`; you don't need to know the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to study trees data structure. If you make a list of trees, and consider each tree root is a person, every subsequent node is a task... so this way you can iterate over all trees and nodes finding all combined possibilities.

Comment: I had such a thing in Programming course in college last year. Gonna give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, what you want are not permutations, but [combinations with repetitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). 
I've found existing implementation for Java: http://code.google.com/p/combinatoricslib/

EDIT (regarding comment):

The problem is even more complicated than combinations with repetitions. It is described here as [Partition of a set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set).

Comment: Well, technically, order is important, so for three tasks `Person1, Person2, Person1` is a different solution from `Person1, Person1, Person2`. Wouldn't that make it permutations? However, the implementation seems useful, so thanks!

Comment: Just importance of order doesn't make anything a permutation :) However you're right, that combinations with repetitions are not enough. I've updated the answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion would do the job, but be aware that it will become computationally infeasible very very quickly so I would suggest a different approach depending on what exactly your goal is with this information. Actually, it will become infeasible so quickly that if there are more than say 4 or 5 people on your team and more than a few tasks the code will never* finish.

*approximately